# facing an error while installing jupyter notebook in windows 10 pro, python3.8.0 using command prompt

Tags: python-3.x

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Fazle L1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-in9a_swm\\pywinpty\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Fazle L1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-in9a_swm\\pywinpty\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Fazle L1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-in9a_swm\pywinpty\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\Fazle L1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-in9a_swm\pywinpty\
    Complete output (147 lines):
    Unable to find pgen, not compiling formal grammar.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 163, in run
        self.run_command("egg_info")
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 283, in run
        self.mkpath(self.egg_info)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 338, in mkpath
        dir_util.mkpath(name, mode, dry_run=self.dry_run)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\distutils\dir_util.py", line 70, in mkpath
        os.mkdir(head, mode)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 310, in wrap
        path = self._remap_input(name, path, *args, **kw)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 452, in _remap_input
        self._violation(operation, os.path.realpath(path), *args, **kw)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 407, in _violation
        raise SandboxViolation(operation, args, kw)
    setuptools.sandbox.SandboxViolation: SandboxViolation: mkdir('C:\\Users\\FAZLEL~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\easy_install-tsax775m\\Cython-0.29.13\\Cython.egg-info', 511) {}
```

The package setup script has attempted to modify files on your system
that are not within the EasyInstall build area, and has been aborted.

This package cannot be safely installed by EasyInstall, and may not
support alternate installation locations even if you run its setup
script by hand.  Please inform the package's author and the EasyInstall
maintainers to find out if a fix or workaround is available.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
    yield saved
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
    _execfile(setup_script, ns)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
    exec(code, globals, locals)
  File "C:\Users\FAZLEL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-tsax775m\Cython-0.29.13\setup.py", line 228, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 163, in setup
    raise SystemExit("error: " + str(msg))
SystemExit: error: SandboxViolation: mkdir('C:\\Users\\FAZLEL~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\easy_install-tsax775m\\Cython-0.29.13\\Cython.egg-info', 511) {}

The package setup script has attempted to modify files on your system
that are not within the EasyInstall build area, and has been aborted.

This package cannot be safely installed by EasyInstall, and may not
support alternate installation locations even if you run its setup
script by hand.  Please inform the package's author and the EasyInstall
maintainers to find out if a fix or workaround is available.


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1144, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 253, in run_setup
    raise
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 166, in save_modules
    saved_exc.resume()
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 141, in resume
    six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
    yield saved
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
    _execfile(setup_script, ns)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
    exec(code, globals, locals)
  File "C:\Users\FAZLEL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-tsax775m\Cython-0.29.13\setup.py", line 228, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 163, in setup
    raise SystemExit("error: " + str(msg))
SystemExit: error: SandboxViolation: mkdir('C:\\Users\\FAZLEL~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\easy_install-tsax775m\\Cython-0.29.13\\Cython.egg-info', 511) {}

The package setup script has attempted to modify files on your system
that are not within the EasyInstall build area, and has been aborted.

This package cannot be safely installed by EasyInstall, and may not
support alternate installation locations even if you run its setup
script by hand.  Please inform the package's author and the EasyInstall
maintainers to find out if a fix or workaround is available.


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Fazle L1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-in9a_swm\pywinpty\setup.py", line 68, in <module>
    setup(
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 144, in setup
    _install_setup_requires(attrs)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 139, in _install_setup_requires
    dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 716, in fetch_build_eggs
    resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 780, in resolve
    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1065, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1077, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 786, in fetch_build_egg
    return cmd.easy_install(req)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 679, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 705, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 890, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1158, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1146, in run_setup
    raise DistutilsError("Setup script exited with %s" % (v.args[0],))
distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: SandboxViolation: mkdir('C:\\Users\\FAZLEL~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\easy_install-tsax775m\\Cython-0.29.13\\Cython.egg-info', 511) {}

The package setup script has attempted to modify files on your system
that are not within the EasyInstall build area, and has been aborted.

This package cannot be safely installed by EasyInstall, and may not
support alternate installation locations even if you run its setup
script by hand.  Please inform the package's author and the EasyInstall
maintainers to find out if a fix or workaround is available.

----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.`pip install jupyter`

Answer (score 6):

As far as I can tell, you have a problem installing the `pywinpty` package. Try to install it alone to see, if I am correct.
As of the time of this post, the people responsible for the package haven't published a `wheel` for Python 3.8 (look for `cp38` in the column `Python version` on the [PyPI entry page](https://pypi.org/project/pywinpty/#files) and compare that to the one for [numpy](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/#files)). There are plans (see this [GIT issue](https://github.com/spyder-ide/pywinpty/issues/123)) to do so, but they haven't so far. The following solution was partly specified in that thread as well.

### Install `pywinpty` manually

1. An unofficial `wheel` can be found [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pywinpty). Look for `cp38` in the file name and download the correct file for your Python version (32 or 64 bit).
2. Open a shell and execute the command seen below. Change the name of the file according to the one you have downloaded. This will install the package manually from the specified `wheel`.

```bsh
python -m pip install .\pywinpty-0.5.5-cp38-cp38-win32.whl
```

3. Now you can install `jupyter` normally. The required package is now installed and your installation should be successful.

Once the official `wheel` is published `pip` should be able to install `jupyter` automatically without this workaround.

Comment: I'm unable to install .\pywinpty-0.5.7-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl in my system while installing this it throws an error like this.


ERROR: pywinpty-0.5.7-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: I am surprised that this answer has not been accepted. Thumbs up from me @SkipperWR

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you should make sure that your pip is upgraded.
Try changing the network, the speed of the network is also an important factor here. I don't know why but it is.
Apparently, pip doesn't like to wait for the pywinpty to get installed so if you have a fast network the error should go away
it worked for me at least...